# Check if line has parameter else skip the line

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I have this:

```
if (line.Contains("nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq"))
{
    var temp = line.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
    if (temp.Length > 1)
    {
         var result2 = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
         //result2[1].Split(')')[0].Dump();
         listNames.Add(result2);
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(result2);      
}
```

and this is for the output:

```
Console.WriteLine("Url " + "\t\t\t\tLast Name");
int index = -1;

foreach (var key in times.Keys)
{
    if (key.Contains("Url"))
    {
        index++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds, "\t\t" + listNames[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

and this are the lines I use:

```
23.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/  qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(johanna huisman)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=date_main:[18980000 TO 19773112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(16209514))&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(16209514))&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=230&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
2014-08-25 15:36:32,246 DEV avqih5cp053gloqfdtd5iaez    0   Q   .   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(Pieter van der Meulen)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=(fk_province:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=20&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
2014-08-25 15:36:32,324 DEV avqih5cp053gloqfdtd5iaez    89  R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(Pieter van der Meulen)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=(fk_province:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=20&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
2014-08-25 15:36:32,698 DEV 1eltnkbwb1na30pvxp5nsaxi    0   Q   .   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(willem breedenoord)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
2014-08-25 15:36:32,730 DEV 1eltnkbwb1na30pvxp5nsaxi    35  R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(willem breedenoord)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
2014-08-25 15:36:32,792 DEV 0pqbpdeurbtlp312ysf12nu1    2321    R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=*:*&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=date_main:[17000101 TO 18503112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
```

So if a line contains the parameter: nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq

Then it has to display the result, otherwise skipe the line. But I get the error:Index was outside the bounds of the array. by this code:

```
catch (Exception e)   
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to access the source file at {0}", sourceFile);
}
```

oke, If I do it like this:

```
var source = "2014-08-25 15:36:32,730 DEV 1eltnkbwb1na30pvxp5nsaxi  35  R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(willem breedenoord)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true"; 
string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };
var temp = source.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
var result = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
result.Dump("Result: ");
```

I get the error:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

But If I do it like this:

```
var source = "2014-08-25 15:36:32,792 DEV 0pqbpdeurbtlp312ysf12nu1  2321    R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=*:*&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=date_main:[17000101 TO 18503112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true"; 
string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };
var temp = source.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
var result = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
result.Dump("Result: ");
```

then the result will be: 
Result:

broekhuijzen

But I have more lines in the textfile, so if not found, then skip.

oke, I have it now like this:

```
var source = "2014-08-25 15:36:32,792 DEV 0pqbpdeurbtlp312ysf12nu1  2321    R   O   http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=*:*&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqbroekhuijzenqxq)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=date_main:[17000101 TO 18503112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true"; 
string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };
var temp = source.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if(temp.Length > 1)
{
temp[1].Split(')')[0].Dump();
//var result = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
//result.Dump("Result: ");
}
```

and the result is: broekhuijzenqxq. But it has to be: broekhuijzen, so without the qxq

I just dont understand why it goes wrong here:

```
foreach (var key in times.Keys)
            {
                if (key.Contains("Url"))
                {
                    index++;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} {2}",key, times[key].TotalSeconds, "\t\t" + listNames[index]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
                }
            }
```

it counts 9 - so that is correct, But I still get the error byt this line: listNames[index]); -

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: what's the try on? seems like you're aiming at a file that isn't there

Comment: ? ofcourse I have the file, that is not the problem.  const string sourceFile = @"testSolar.txt"; but the problem is that it doesnt skipe the line when the property nosyn_name_last_exact doesnt exist in the file

Comment: Not very clear how you're using what and what you're expecting where. what is the `times`, what does it have to do with `listNames` (if at all), and so on.

Comment: I've changed my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be :
You're splitting and trying to access the element at index 1 of the array here: `var temp = source.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];`
obviously, if the split does not contain your separator, you won't have that element, so you'll get an out of bounds exception.

You should only have that bit of code **INSIDE** the block where you check that the `source` variable actually has your `.Contains("nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq"))`.

---

Try:

```
if (line.Contains("nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq"))
{
  string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
  string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };
  var temp = line.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
  var result = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
  result.Dump("Result: ");
}
```

shouldn't throw

Comment: The way you ask or comment is by leaving comments. Not by editing the answer. You can edit your question if you want though. In any case, if you still run into the out of array exception, put a debug point there, and make sure your array has the item you're trying to access (which, obviously, it's not, since it throws an exception, but in your code it'll be easy to figure out why or what's happening)